# ReactJS Failed Prop Type With 'undefined' Value

Tags: reactjs, validation, types

I've looked at other similar questions but can't seem to find an answer...

I'm getting error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `height` is marked as required in `AudioPlayer`, but its value is `undefined`.

When trying the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Audio from "react-audioplayer";
import "./../../Assets/Css/AudioPlayer.css";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class AudioPlayer extends Component {
    render(props) {
        const playlist = this.props.playlist;

        const AudioStyles = {
            width: "99%",
            margin: "1% 0"
        };

        const AudioProps = {
            height: 600,
            style: AudioStyles,
            playlist: playlist,
            fullPlayer: true
        };

        return (
            <Row>
                <Col xs={12}>
                    <Audio {...AudioProps} />
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}

AudioPlayer.propTypes = {
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
```

The code still functions as expected but gives the error mentioned above.

Should I be checking prop types differently?

Comment: can you show how are you rendering `AudioPlayer` ?

Comment: What do you not understand about the error?

Comment: You do not need `AudioPlayer.propTypes = {
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};`. it is needed in Audio component.

Comment: Thanks guys, oversight on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see in your question description, uou have no dependency of `prop height` in the `AudioPlayer` component. You would rather want it in the `Audio` Component and hence you need to specify `Proptype` for the `Audio component`

so In the Audio component file add  and remove from `AudioPlayer` component file.

```
Audio.propTypes = {
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Argh - thanks, too much staring - will accept when I can, thanks!